# Restarting pomodoro

Tags: org-mode

If I start clock on an item, I can use `org-clock-jump-to-current-clock` and it always takes me to the current item (from any buffer).

After you clock-out, you cannot jump to `current-clock` anymore and that makes sense.

But what if I started the timer via [`org-pomodoro`](https://github.com/lolownia/org-pomodoro)? Then after it clocks out, in order to start another cycle I'd have to:

- open the .org buffer with the task I'm trying to clock
- run `org-pomodoro` while on the task item

*this will add a row to the item's CLOCK drawer (or whatever you have set in `org-clock-into-drawer` variable)*

So the question is:

**Is there more efficient way to restart the timer on the last (clocked) item?**

Without having to find and open the .org buffer?

Answer (score 2):

> `C-c C-x C-i     (org-clock-in)`
>
> Start the clock on the current item (clock-in). ...
>
> When called with a C-u prefix argument, select the task from a list of
>   recently clocked tasks.

`info:(org) Clocking commands`

Comment: but that won't start the pomodoro, it would just clock-in.

Comment: Oh. Then you'd have to afterwards jump to the running clock and call your pomodoro function. A fun project if you want to try a bit of elisp.

Comment: actually, I just discovered that if you run `M-x` `org-pomodoro`  - it will ask you which task you want you to start on. Must be a recent feature.

Comment: OMG. I love Emacs. thanks for telling me to RTFM. By going to `M-x info` and reading "Clocking commands", I have generated a few awesome ideas how to take my usage of pomodoro to the next level.